# c++ sort vector of pair objects, compile error asking for operator "="

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector like this:

```
vector<pair<const MyObj&, MyStrut>> alls;
```

When I do

```
swap(alls[0], alls[1]);
```

It complained

binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion

Why?

Comment: Generally speaking a `const MyObj &` cannot be assigned to, since it is `const`.   Assignment of a `pair<X, Y>` generally works by doing an assignment of `X` and an assignment of `Y` and, if either of them cannot be assigned, neither can the pair.   The default implementation of `swap` does assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of trying to swap your `pair`s, it's intrinsically trying to assign from a `const` reference to a `const` reference. You can't rebind a reference, so the only thing it could conceivably do is swap the objects referred to by each reference. But since these are `const` references, even that's impossible.

If you think you need to store a reference in a data structure and manipulate the structure containing it in any way, it's usually the case that you actually want to store a pointer of some sort (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`) that would allow you to store it in the data structure and reassign (e.g. `swap`) it within the data structure, while still having an owned pointer to it somewhere else (to preserve the "referenciness" you're relying on).